# /bin/sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I am developing my C++ code in Eclipse. I have seen this problem before on stackoverflow. But I haven't modified makefile in anyway. I was only modifying my cpp files.. I'm unaware how this error came from nowhere!
Here's the the error log :

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/linksmart/development/installs/smartdna_build/opencv-2.4.6.1/lib -o "smartDNAReaderMerged"  ./src/zbar/BarcodeIdentifier.o  ./src/xml/pugixml.o  ./src/opencv/CircleValidator.o ./src/opencv/ImageProcessor\ (copy).o ./src/opencv/ImageProcessor.o  ./src/mysql/Database.o  ./src/models/AudioPlayer.o ./src/models/Camera.o ./src/models/CredentialConfigurator.o  ./src/algorithms/CircleSorter.o ./src/algorithms/CredentialValidator.o ./src/algorithms/LabelValidator.o  ./src/ApplicationManager.o ./src/encryptor.o ./src/login.o ./src/main.o ./src/motion.o ./src/smartdna.o ./src/sound.o ./src/webservice.o   -lfltk_images -lfltk_gl -lfltk_cairo -lfltk -lcurl -lzbar -lsqlite3 -lasound -lmysqlcppconn -lMagick++ -lMagickCore -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `g++ -L/home/linksmart/development/installs/smartdna_build/opencv-2.4.6.1/lib -o "smartDNAReaderMerged"  ./src/zbar/BarcodeIdentifier.o  ./src/xml/pugixml.o  ./src/opencv/CircleValidator.o ./src/opencv/ImageProcessor\ (copy).o ./src/opencv/ImageProcessor.o  ./src/mysql/Database.o  ./src/models/AudioPlayer.o ./src/models/Camera.o ./src/models/CredentialConfigurator.o  ./src/algorithms/CircleSorter.o ./src/algorithms/CredentialValidator.o ./src/algorithms/LabelValidator.o  ./src/ApplicationManager.o ./src/encryptor.o ./src/login.o ./src/main.o ./src/motion.o ./src/smartdna.o ./src/sound.o ./src/webservice.o   -lfltk_images -lfltk_gl -lfltk_cairo -lfltk -lcurl -lzbar -lsqlite3 -lasound -lmysqlcppconn -lMagick++ -lMagickCore -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_video -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy'
make: *** [smartDNAReaderMerged] Error 1
```

Comment: What about this? `./src/opencv/ImageProcessor\ (copy).o ` Seems like you screwed up some filename?

Comment: Brackets have a special meaning to the `shell` so you need to get them escaped.

Comment: had to delete the erroneously copied file

Comment: This is why I never use `$(wildcard *.cpp)` or `$(shell find ...)` or whatever to get "all the sources".  I always list the source files explicitly in the makefile.  How often does one create a new source file?  It's not so hard to add the filename directly to the makefile in those fairly rare situations, and it prevents lots of strange errors like this.